# Quadratics/Algebra word Problem (based on physics)

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, kinematics

There is a problem from an old high school math book I have.
It appears in a chapter on quadratics and polynomials.
It uses constant velocity, so hence it is physics based type of problem.

Over the years I have come back to this problem, and could never figure it out. I once took this problem to a university Masters student studying "Algebraic Geometry", but he gave me a very convoluted answer, or I should maybe say he gave me an abstract method to solve this, which later I could not figure out.

So here is the question:

> Two runners start at the opposite sides of a $60$ meter field. One person runs at $4$ m/s, the other person runs at $5$ m/s. If they run back and forth for $12$ minutes, how many times with they pass each other.

Answer in the book is: They pass each other $54$ times.

I have no idea how to model this problem.

Hope someone knows how to figure this problem out.

Regards,

P

Comment: Though I do not have an answer (yet), I was able to graph this problem in Desmos, having all the crossings visible. You might be interested: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pgsbyry5c9

Comment: Hi Mark, I really like what you did with Desmos.com, its a nice way to illustrate this problem. I liked the fact that you created algebraic functions here, because i believe that is what the problem is looking for.

Comment: @Palu Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 3):

Relative to one of the runners, the other runner approaches their next meeting at a speed of $4+5=9$m/s. So if you imagine one of the runners is stationary from the beginning, the other runner is doing all the running at $9$m/s.

In $12$ minutes this runner will cover a distance of $9\times 12\times 60$ metres and he meets the stationary runner every $120$ metres, so the number of times they meet is $$\frac{9\times 12\times 60}{120}=54$$

Comment: Hi David Quinn, I really like your answer, to me its solved closer to a physics based way, which I do like, but since the book is a math book, i believe its expecting a very algebraic way of solving this, while thru physics principles you were able to reduce this to an arithmetic problem. I think your way of doing it is pure genius. BUT i think its not the approach expected.

Comment: Hi Palu. There are probably lots of ways of doing this problem but I bet there are no simple solutions involving quadratics and polynomials. You have your own views on what constitutes a physics solution as opposed to a maths solution. For me there is no difference. For me the best solution is one which is simple to understand.

Comment: Yes, I agree  David with what you say as well. The thing that made it more Physics is making one of the runners stationary, because that is looking at things from a particular Frame of Reference, (ie. Galilean transformation ideas), and in the highschools in my country, they teach this kind of way of thinking in physic class and not in math class. So that is where my ideas of what is math and what is physics comes from.

Answer (score 1):

In the first minute the faster runner runs the field 5 times while the slower runners runs the field 4 times, thus they cross 4 times + 1 time and after a minute the start toghether from the same side. In the second minute they cross again 4 times and then at the end of the second minute the are again at opposite sides. Since the same cicle of 2 minute repeates 6 times,they cross $9\times6=54$ times.

Comment: Hi gimusi, as I commented to David, i thought Davids answer was very very good, but I am looking for an algebraic way, with functions etc to do this. Your answer is a word based explanation, and I have a bit difficulty following it. Your explanation makes claims without real proof. But even if you did, like I mentioned I am looking for an algebraic solution.

Answer (score 0):

The faster runner crosses the field 60 times, and the slower runner 48 times.  Since they each cross the field an even number of times, they end up where they started.  Since the faster runner crosses the field more often, he must overtake the runner sometimes.  (This is not counted as a cross.)  In order for him to overtake a second time, the runners must first cross.  So, the $12$ extra laps consist of $6$ overtakes and $6$ crosses, and there are $48 + 6 = 54$ crosses in all.